# Is there a relationship between temperature and pressure of a refrigerant?

Tags: heat-transfer, pressure

When searching for a pressure temperature relation for a refrigerant a chart appears.

But I was wondering are these charts made by experimenting on the refrigerant or is there a relationship which can be applied for every refrigerant in order to determine the temperature of the refrigerant at that specific temperature

Comment: Check out Charles law and Boyles law.

Comment: Quite a few are mixtures, and basically, you have to experiment, although some behave fairly well as far as being a linear combination of their constituents. Because there are so many of them (wiki lists about 470 of them), and they are typically used in a region of nonlinear behavior, it is better to run off charts. Or you can use a high-end real gas model that gets the behavior correct at the liquid-vapor transition. But these are computationally intensive in a CFD environment.